# nginx 404 error upon refresh on react application

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have a docker container running two different applications, one is written on angular and one is written on react. While i can access both applications under my browser if I will navigate under my react application and refresh any subpage I get a 404 error under my browser. The only way to refresh is when I am under the root path /admin

I have tried to find a way by using the search function under stackoverflow as many others had the same issue with nginx but none of the available solutions worked. I believe its because I am running both applications under the same container and I have to write some short of special code

Below you may find my nginx configuration

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {

    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
      listen 8080;
      client_max_body_size 1G;
      root /opt/static;

      location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        error_page 405 = $uri;
      }

      location /admin {
        alias /usr/src/admin;
      }
      proxy_connect_timeout       600;
      proxy_send_timeout          600;
      proxy_read_timeout          600;
      send_timeout                600;
    }
}
```

Where /opt/static = angular application and /usr/src/admin = react application.

Basically I login under Angular and the administration portion is being build under react.